# How to make gcc/g++ accept expressions like LOBYTE(v15) = someExpression?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

I have a decompiled function and want to compile its source. The problem is with LOBYTE statements: 
get "error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment" on every line like that:

```
LOBYTE(v9) = ((_BYTE)v12 + (v7 ^ v13)) & 0x1F;
```

Tip a workaround, please.

Comment: How would we possibly know what `LOBYTE` is?

Comment: In particular, it reasonably could be the least significant bits of v9, or the byte with the lowest address. On big-endian systems, those are at opposite ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `v9` is an object of an arithmetic type (the question does not explicit the declarations of the different identifiers / macros involved) and the system is little-endian:

```
#define LOBYTE(x)  (*(unsigned char *) &(x))
```

would allow `LOBYTE` on the left hand side of the `=` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `LOBYTE` is some variable in which you can strore some value. It's a `MACRO` which returns a value itself. In effet you're writing something simmilar to [after preprocessing]

`5 = 2 * 3`

which is not possible. You'll need some *writable* memory on the LHS of the assignment `=` operator.

In your case, a possible implementation of `LOBYTE` is `#define LOBYTE(x) ((unsigned char) ((x) & 0xff))`, which is not a `lvalue`. That's why the error is there.

---

EDIT:

Regarding the "how to solve" part [sorry for missing in first answer], you need to provide the lvalue as an outcome of LOBYTE.

Just to add to [ouah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1119701/ouah)'s answer, you can do do something like

```
#define LOBYTE(x)  (*(uint8_t *) &(x))
```

to produce the required lvalue .

Comment: @MattMcNabb Sorry sir, did not get your point. Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: to use a variable on the left of equal sign, you need it to be an lvalue

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Sir, thank you for explaining. However, I wanted to show the particular implementation of `LOBYTE` which might have caused the error in OP's case. In that case, am I correct?

Comment: that's not your initial wording. and don't call me sir

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc As you wish !! As per the latest edit, my answer is correct, right?

Comment: the OP asked *how*, not *why*